# Python - Multiple Login Combinations

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

Basically, I've made a basic login program that accepts user input. But, it currently only allows one username and password combo. I'm trying to make it accept multiple usernames and passwords but don't know how to. I am new to python and I know my code is terrible/messy. This is what I've been trying to get it to accept multiple login combinations:

```
output = open("logfile.txt", 'a')
login = input("please enter the correct username and password\n")
a = ("username password")("username1 password1")

if a in login:
    print("successfully logged in")
    import time
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    output.write("Somebody successfully logged in at ")
    output.write(localtime)
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()


else:
    print("access denied.")
    import time
    output = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")
    output.write(localtime)
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()
```

`
When I just add another 'if' block, it runs the else block aswell. Also, when I just have 'a' value "username password" it works. The problem is when I try to have multiple values I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a = set(("username password","username1 password1"))
if login in a:
```

and it should work as you expect.

Why is left as an exercise (hint: print the value of a).

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that easy. Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `a = ("username password")("username1 password1")` and `if a in login:`.

You want to set `a` to an iterable of some sort, the code you currently have actually produces a `TypeError` because you are trying to call a string (putting something in brackets doesn't make it a tuple, you need to add a trailing comma).

What you want instead is something like `a = ["username password", "username1 password1"]`, doe create a list with all the valid usernames and passwords. You then want to check if the input - `login` - is in that list, so do `if login in a:` instead.